# What is wrong about my attempt to define the / operator on Dictionary<string,int>?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to make a function that takes the difference of two `Dictionary<string,int>`s, e.g.

```
{ "SomeKey" -> 4 , "SomeOtherKey" -> 2 } / { "SomeKey" -> 1, "Keykeykey" -> 69 }
= { "SomeKey -> 3" , "SomeOtherKey" -> 2 }
```

My procedure is

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> operator / ( Dictionary<string, int> first, Dictionary<string, int> second )
    {
        // Returns all elements in first but not second, where the number in the first but not second
        // for a given key is the first's value minus the second's value
        Dictionary<string, int> firstNotSecond = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in first )
        {
            int secondNum = second.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? second[pair.Key] : 0;
            if ( pair.Value > secondNum )
            {
                firstNotSecond[pair.Key] = pair.Value - secondNum;
            }
        }
        return firstNotSecond;
    }
```

and when I try to use it in the case

```
        Dictionary<string, int> friendsGained = latestTwo[0].names / latestTwo[1].names,
                                  friendsLost = latestTwo[1].names / latestTwo[0].names;
```

I get the compile-time error

> Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>`' and
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,int>`'

What gives?

Comment: You should not use operator-overloading for such complex and more important quite confusing mechanism. Create a method that describes what you want to achieve by this operation instead. Furthermore the operator as it is defined statically means that you may devide EVERY dictionary of type `string, int` by another which is supposed to be whrong.

Comment: Do you not get a compiler error on the operator definition? What class are you writing it within? You should get an error because none of the operands are your class's type.

Comment: You can only overload an operator for a class C inside class C. So you would have to edit the source code for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Write a(n) (extension) method instead.

Comment: Well I thought this would be more elegant than writing a function like `DicDifference<TKey,TValue> ( Dictionary<TKey,TValue> first, Dictionary<TKey,Value> second )` is the only reason I tried to make it

Comment: Well, for making a difference I suppose a minus would be more adequate. However don´t do it, its quite confusing and misleading.

Comment: It's much more "elegant" to write a method `DicDifference` or `SubtractValuesByKey` than to provide an operator that nobody at all will ever understand or even notice.

Answer (score 2):

When implementing a *binary operator* like `/` at least one argument should be of *class you are implementing*.

```
  public class MyClass {
    ...
    // Doesn't compile:
    // Either "first" or "second" should be of MyClass type
    public static Dictionary<string, int> operator / 
      (Dictionary<string, int> first, Dictionary<string, int> second) {...}
    ...
  }
```

I suggest using *extension method*, e.g.

```
public static DictionaryExtensions {
  public static Dictionary<K, int> Subtract(this IDictionary<K, int> first, 
                                                 IDictionary<K, int> second) {
    if (null == first)
      return null; // or throw new ArgumentNullException("first");  
    else if (null == second)
      return first.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value); // let it be copy
             // or throw new ArgumentNullException("second");  

    Dictionary<K, int> result = new Dictionary<K, int>();

    foreach (var pair in first) {
      int secondNum;

      if (second.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out secondNum)) 
        if (pair.Value > secondName) 
          result.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value - secondNum);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

So you can put it

```
  Dictionary<string, int> friendsGained = latestTwo[0].names.Subtract(latestTwo[1].names);
  Dictionary<string, int> friendsLost = latestTwo[1].names.Subtract(latestTwo[0].names);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested you need to have your class as part of the operator.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> YourProperty...

     public static Dictionary<string, int> operator / ( YourClass first, Dictionary<string, int> second )
    {
        // Returns all elements in first but not second, where the number in the first but not second
        // for a given key is the first's value minus the second's value
        Dictionary<string, int> firstNotSecond = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in first.YourProperty )
        {
            int secondNum = second.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? second[pair.Key] : 0;
            if ( pair.Value > secondNum )
            {
                firstNotSecond[pair.Key] = pair.Value - secondNum;
            }
        }
        return firstNotSecond;
    }
}
```